# Java Applet does not start

Tags: java, applet

i have the following structure in Eclipse:

foo.bar.app as package, containing Main.java and Applet.java (not sure if thie ifnormation is needed...)

I can run the appliacation fine in eclipse either as Java(swing) application or applet. Now i am trying to run it into a brwoser (Must only work in FireFox...)

So i made a right-click on the project -> Export -> jar (not runnable jar!), and moved it into the folder /home/user/Desktop/test

The folder test contains the following index.html:

```
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
    <body> 
        <p> 
            <embed id = "test"  
            type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6" 
            width="256" height="256" 
            archive="test.jar" 
            code="foo.bar.app.Applet.class" 
            /> 
        </p> 
</body>
```

But all I got is a Grey Box... At the bottom FireFox says Start: applet not initalized.

Here is a snippet

```
public class Applet extends JApplet {

@Override
public void init() {
    super.init();

    // simulate properties file, empty properties should have no influence
    Properties p = new Properties();

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setSize(1000, 600);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an error starting the applet. Try to open the "Java Console" (not the Java **Script** console); [the Mozilla Knowledge Base tells you how](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Java).

You should be able to see the stack trace in the console.